# add property for a object dynamicly

Tags: java, reflection

Hi:
In our application,we have retrive some data from the database,for example,the table have columes:id,name,age,address,email.

Then we will get some of these propertis according to the client.

If client need the id, name, we get the id name, if client need id, name, age, we get the id, name, age.

Now we want to create a class to wrap these properties. However we do not know exactly which field are requested.

```
String[] requestPro={"name","id"}; //this field is specified by client
Map<String, Object> map=new HashMap<String, Object>();
Entity en=Entity.newInstance();
for(String p:requestPro){
    map.put(p, BeanUtils.getProperty(en, p));
}
```

Here can I replace the map with a Class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand you right, you want to dynamically add properties to a class, or rather: to a specific instance of a class.

The former is possible e.g. in Groovy, where there is a metaclass object for every class, to which you can assign behavior at runtime, the latter is possible in JavaScript, where you can assign behavior both to an object's prototype and to an object itself. But neither of those versions is possible in Java, so using a Map or a similar structure is the thing to do in Java.

Comment: You can do this in Java.  See how here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215536/java-dynamic-properties

Comment: @HDave Funny, the two top answers to that question say it can't be done. And Pascal's answer only works with CGLib, a byte code manipulation library. So, ok you *can* do it in Java if you are ready to modify classes on the fly and tamper with classloaders. But hardly anybody does that and there are reasons for that. It's hacky and error-prone. The groovy metaclass approach is much cleaner and safer.

Comment: I think it's possible by subclassing Object to give it an additional HashMap mapping from String to the subclass of object. Then you can add the properties via subclass methods such as addEntry and removeEntry. It will need reflection to deal with handling each object on per-object basis, but this isn't bad since you know what they are, just looks ugly.