# How to add dynamic object and list as key value into the list of hash map items

Tags: java

Here there is java snippet for the list of hash map contains the data.
so finally I have the data with the list of hash map.

```
List<HashMap<String,object>> data = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();
HashMap<String,object> dataMap = new HashMap<String,object>();

dataMap.add("id",1);
dataMap.add("source","Database");
dataMap.add("address","USA");
data.add(dataMap);
```

And here is one JavaScript code snippet:

```js
var dataMap = items.reduce(function(a,b){
a[b.id]=b;
b.data ={};
b.children=[];
},{})
```

My question is: how do I add **data object** and **children array** into the java list[dataMap] of hash map same denoted in javascript.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [add property for a object dynamicly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323328/add-property-for-a-object-dynamicly)

Comment: It looks like you are using a Map as a rudimentary class (hence the String key as a field and the type Object as the field's value).  Presuming I am correct, why not just use  a class?  It may simplify your task considerably.