# C++ Redefining Class Method for Specific Objects

Tags: c++, class, pointers, object

I have a class `foo` that has a method `doesSomething()`. I construct multiple objects of said class, but for a few specific ones I want `doesSomething()` to do something else. How do I redefine the body of that method dynamically after construction?

I believe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849963/dynamically-reassign-method-bodies-to-objects) is exactly what I'm looking for, but it's in Java.

Comment: Do you know javascript?

Comment: Yes, I do, but I'm asking for C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to "overwrite" a previous class definition, you can use virtual functions, and use a derived class.

[Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/polymorphism/) you have some examples, particularly under the "Virtual members" title.

Good luck.

Comment: I've considered this option, but creating a new derived class seems a little overkill for just modifying one method.

Comment: If you want to modify the method, but keep the original for some other object, you have to do it. Two objects from the same class will always have the same methods. If the methods are different, they need to be different classes. EDIT: Other work-around, is to define a variable of status, and put an if inside the method. That way you can change back and forth without problems in the same object.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct nasty_object {
  nasty_object() 
  : _something_do { std::bind(&nasty_object::normal_thing, this) }
  {
  }

  void normal_thing() {
    // the stuff to do in the default case
  }

  void do_other_thing() {
    // the stuff to do in the alternate case
  }

  void do_something() {
    if(_something_do) {
      _something_do();
    }
  }

  // replace the meaning of 'do_something()'
  void set_do_something(std::function<void()> f)
  {
    _something_do(std::move(f));
  }

private:
  std::function<void()> _something_do;
};
```

now you can create objects and change the meaning of do_something() at run time like this

```
auto n1 = nasty_object{};
auto n2 = nasty_object{};
auto n3 = nasty_object{};
n2.set_do_something(std::bind(&nasty_object::do_other_thing, &n2));
n3.set_do_something([&n3] {
  // do something totally different!
});
n1.do_something(); // does something
n2.do_something(); // does the other thing
n3.do_something(); // does whatever was in your lambda
```

Note: just because you *can* do this with c++ does not mean you should. This kind of irresponsible behaviour is best left to script-jockeys and other people up to no good.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, objects don't have references to methods, they have references to "virtual function tables" aka "classes".  So you'd need to involve another class to do it the way you envisage. But you also said you want to change it after the object has been constructed - and that means you can't do it using virtual functions. Instead you should use function pointers or even just a simple boolean:

```
class C {
    bool isSpecial;

    void doesSomethingNormal() { ... }
    void doesSomethingSpecial() { ... }
    void doesSomething() { 
              if (isSpecial) 
                  doesSomethingSpecial();
              else doesSomethingNormal();
    }
};
```