# Dynamic class loading mechanism

Tags: java, reflection, proxy

My requirement is that I am having a class Employee as:-

```
class Employee {
     private String firstName;
}
```

Under some conditions I want to add two more fields dynamically to Employee class, let say lastName and middleName. The option is certainly using reflection. That is later part. The doubt is:-

As the code is going to be used in web application. So, as per my understanding, per request as per the above logic, a new class will be formed and loaded by the class loader?

If yes, then there would be lot of classes in JVM. Am I right?

I get from some hyperlinks about the approach [Java: dynamic properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215536/java-dynamic-properties) and [add property for a object dynamicly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323328/add-property-for-a-object-dynamicly).

But I want to calculate the implications first.

Comment: have you considered just having a map of objects? Would require some casting of objects, but would allow you not have to deal with reflection

Comment: And what about creating a sub class of Employee yourself ?

Comment: Yes there are other approaches also but i want to consider the implications first of this approach just for gaining knowledge. :->

Comment: @Mohit Ok, it's for training, go to know ;)